# How to set a bean property before executing this f:event listener

Tags: java, jsf

How to set a bean property from jsf page before executing this f:event listener:

```
    <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="bean.method}"/>
```

I tried the below code but it does not set the value to the bean property.

```
    <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="bean.method}">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.howMany}" value="2"/>
    </f:event>
```

---

JSF2.1.6 with PF 3.3

---

### EDIT

Any issues with this below code? (This works! but I just want to confirm if there are any issues with this!?)

> ```
> <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{bean.setHowMany(15)}"/> 
> <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{bean.method}"/>
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
<f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{bean.method('2')}"/>
```

And if that wont work , try

```
<f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{bean.method}">
    <f:attribute name="howMany" value="2" />
</f:event>
```

and in you managed bean add the following

```
public void method(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    String howMany = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("howMany");
}
```

I think you better avoid two subsequent `<f:event>` calls , when you don't really need them, Although I think i saw somewhere that the order of declaration will be the order of execution, It still may vary between different JSF implementation and you never can be 100% sure that you can count on it...

so INMO using only one is better in this case

```
<f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{bean.method(15)}"/>
```

Comment: Many Thanks! but any reason to avoid this following way (just striked my mind)..
        
        `<f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{bean.setHowMany(15)}"/>`
        `<f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{bean.method}"/>`