# How to pass parameters to preRenderView event listener

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I´m developing a listener method for the preRenderView event in which I intend intercept the DOM tree components and set the rendered property to true or false according to permissions of logged in user.

I have reviewed these questions but I still have some doubts

[Set Bean property before listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068893/how-to-set-a-bean-property-before-executing-this-fevent-listener)

[Safe Pass Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511738/jsf-fevent-safe-to-pass-parameters)

This is a fragment of my principal template:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="center">

        <p:tabView id="tabItemList" scrollable="true"
            activeIndex="#{borderTemplateMB.activeTab}">

            <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{borderTemplateMB.onCloseTab}" />

            <c:forEach items="#{borderTemplateMB.tabList}" var="tabItem">
                <p:tab closable="#{tabItem.closable}" id="#{tabItem.id}"
                    visible="tabItem.visible">
                    <f:facet name="title">
                        <span class="ui-icon #{tabItem.icon}" />
                        <p:outputLabel value=" #{tabItem.title}"></p:outputLabel>
                    </f:facet>
                    <ui:include src="#{tabItem.url}" />
                </p:tab>
            </c:forEach>

        </p:tabView>

    </p:layoutUnit>
```

Inside or each tabs (.xhtml) I have this content:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{securityMB.doManageEvents}" type="preRenderView" />
    <f:attribute name="resource" value="frm_groups" />          
</f:metadata>

<ui:decorate
    template="/protected/templates/#{customerMB.template}/forms/templateSearch.xhtml">

    <ui:param name="tpl_panel_title" value="#{msg['panel.title.groups']}"></ui:param>
    <ui:param name="tpl_title_filters"
        value="#{msg['label.searchFilters']}"></ui:param>
```

The relevants part are this:

***First try***

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{securityMB.doManageEvents}" type="preRenderView" />
    <f:attribute name="resource" value="frm_groups" />          
</f:metadata>
```

In my Request Scoped Bean:

```
public void doManageEvents(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    UIViewRoot root = Faces.getContext().getViewRoot();

    String idForm = (String)event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("resource");

    LOG.info("[doManageEvents] Init " + idForm);
    UIComponent comp = findComponent(root, idForm);
    if (comp != null) {
        printComponentTree(comp);
    }
}
```

this first try fails because the attribute "resource" is not updated, always shows the first called.

***Second Try:***

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{securityMB.doManageEvents}" type="preRenderView">
        <f:attribute name="resource" value="frm_groups" />
    </f:event>          
</f:metadata>
```

At this second try the resource attribute is null.

***Third try:***

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{securityMB.doManageEvents('from_users')}" type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>
```

In my Request Scoped Bean:

```
public void doManageEvents(String idForm) {
    UIViewRoot root = Faces.getContext().getViewRoot();
    LOG.info("[doManageEvents] Init " + idForm);
    UIComponent comp = findComponent(root, idForm);
    if (comp != null) {
        printComponentTree(comp);
    }
}
```

This last approach compile fine and Works, but eclipse shows this error on editor:

```
Method must have signature "void method(ComponentSystemEvent)" but has 
 signature "void method(String)"
```

I need to know what approach to use with this errors on editor.

What is the correct form to send parameters to preRenderView Listener?.

Comment: Use an additional `<f:viewParam>` inside `<f:metadata>` in addition to using `<f:event>`.

Comment: Thanks @Tiny, can you point me to any resource where show how to get the viewParam inside the preRenderView listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Problem**

Your various attempts failed for the following reasons:

1. **You are applying the `f:attribute` on the wrong component and attempting to retrieve it from the wrong component in the backing bean**:

   - `f:attribute` is applicable [only on components that extend `UIComponent`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/vdldocs/facelets/f/attribute.html). `javax.faces.view.ViewMetadata` does not extend `UIComponent` so the `f:attribute` is not applicable on it.
   - Coupled with the following line

     ```
       String idForm = (String)event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("resource");
     ```

   That line above sees you trying to get the attribute from the `ComponentSystemEvent` instance, rather than the metadata object instance that you (erroneously) attempted to attach an attribute to
2. Same as (1), `javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent` is not a child of `UIComponent`
3. You already have the reason why the third approach failed.

---

**To Solve**

JSTL's `<c:set/>` will do just fine *if and only if* the value to set is available at view-build time.

```
<c:set property="#{yourBean.property}" value="theValue"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @kolossus for point me to error, really I do that for another answers, I'll be even more grateful when you complete your Answer "To Solve"

Comment: @JeisonG - sorry I was looking for a more straightforward way to pull the value off the parameter, then I got distracted. There's either no easier way or I'm too fried to think clearly. Either way, this should work until BalusC comes along to point out something simpler

Comment: Thnaks @kolossus but with your suggestion I have the same problem with my first attempt, the value is set first time but is not updated in the next request.

Comment: @JeisonG - use the `c:set` JSTL tag then. Depending on when the value is available(view-build or view-render time), you can use `<c:set property="#{yourBean.property}" value="theValue"/>`

Comment: Ok @kolossus, this `<c:set target="#{securityMB}" property="component" value="frm_roles" />` works for me. Thanks.

Comment: @JeisonG - told you I was fried yesterday :)